I'm experiencing a weird bug with Nautilus file manager on Ubuntu 24.04
So I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 like yesterday and just now I'm experiencing a weird bug with Nautilus, that 1 won't disappear. So here's what happened, I downloaded the Tor Browser from the official Tor website and then "extracted" the download and when it was done extracting I received a pop up telling me the extraction process was complete and that's also when I saw that green 1 show up.

So at first I just restarted my computer thinking that would fix it but to my complete astonishment it was still there when I logged back in. I've even tried unpinning Nautilus and then repinning it to dash but nope that 1 just won't disappear.
I can't get it to disappear. What do I do?
Thanks for your time I appreciate it.

why is the green 1 a problem?

@jsotola Is there anyway I can get rid of it? That's a bug right?

maybe you should be asking what it means, instead of asking how to get rid of it ... don't be too quick to get rid of things that you do not understand

@jsotola So do you know why the green 1 is there and how to get rid of it?

On a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system:

Opened Files (from GNOME)

Inserted a USB drive.

In Files selected to eject the USB drive.

A green one appeared on Files icon on the dash:


Clicked the Clock on the top of the screen and Notifications were displayed. The most recent notification was for Files indicating the USB Mass Storage Device which I had unplugged could be removed:


Clicked on the X on the top right of the Files notification to clear the notification.

The green one was removed from the Files icon on the dash:



I.e. the green numbers on the dash icons appear to be a count of now many outstanding notifications are from an application.
From memory, the previous Ubuntu 22.04 didn't display notifications with a green number on the icons in the dash.

Oh ok gotcha. Thank you.
